# How to easily save all open Safari tabs on iOS?

Tags: ios, safari, tabs

On macOS, I can choose *Add Bookmarks for These 108 Tabs...* which let's me save all open tabs to a bookmarks folder.

Is there an equivalent on iOS?

> My workaround is to use iCloud tabs to copy the tabs from iOS to macOS and then do the above.

edit: as of iOS 13 this function is built in. See answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [MacRumors](https://www.macrumors.com/guide/safari/), this functionality is coming in Safari 13, which will be released with iOS 13, presumably some time this autumn. So if your iOS version is 13 or higher, long-press on the bookmark icon at the bottom of the Safari window and select “Add bookmarks for [x] tabs”.

Comment: Awesome! I'll keep an eye out for it

Answer (score 7):

Best flow I have seen in 2021 is:

1. Press and hold on Bookmark button in mobile Safari > Select 'Add Bookmarks for X Tabs'
2. Put them in a separate folder
3. Press and hold on that bookmark folder > Select 'Copy Contents'
4. Paste the list of URLs to a Note

Now you have all the tabs URLs in text, so you can do whatever you need with them.

Comment: Nice! I was not aware of Copy Contents.

Answer (score 4):

You can find the cloud tabs in `~/Library/Safari/CloudTabs.db`. Copy this file to some unrestricted location, like Downloads.
Use ‘DB Browser for SQLite’ to open the file.

With the following query you'll get your devices:

```
select * from cloud_tab_devices
```

Copy the device_uuid for the iOS device you want to save.

Using this you can run the next query to get a list of the tabs:

```
select url from cloud_tabs where device_uuid='...'
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I was looking for access to synced tabs for a while. You can also use SQLite as a cli tool to explore the data, or even to export it as csv. The command to export just the urls: `sqlite3 -header -csv ~/Library/Safari/CloudTabs.db 'select url from cloud_tabs' > cloud_tabs.csv`. Also, since this is a read-only operation, there's no need to copy the file.

Comment: The location has changed to `~/Library/Containers/com.apple.Safari/Data/Library/Safari/CloudTabs.db`

You also may need to ensure that Terminal has Full Disk Access if you get a _CloudTabs.db: cannot open: Operation not permitted_ error.

Answer (score 3):

**Previously:**

> Not sure but maybe with "Workflow" app ? But I really don't think that
>   that's a thing on iOS. Consider submitting a feedback for it so it
>   might get included one day.

**September 2019:**

As of iOS 13 you can add all the open tabs in bookmark, here is a screenshot of safari I just did

[image: iOS 13 safari update, allows all tabs to be added as bookmarks]

Comment: Good idea to try Workflow. Let me know if you have any specific ideas.

Comment: I checked and there's nothing relevant in Workflow.

Comment: Thanks for updating, but I don't understand the language.